# Is it possible to map Completion field with Context Suggester in spring-data-elasticsearch?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to map field in Entity like @CompletionField, but with contexts, cause now Completion includes String[] and int weight field. I want to filtering completion in index.

```
@Document(indexName = "compl_index")
    public class ComplIndex {
    @CompletionField
    private Completion suggestions;
   }
```

When I write this class, I have a simple completion with string array and weight, but I want to map entity like this, and work with contexts. I try to solve this problem - write a new entity with fields type, contexts etc and annotate with Mapping, CompletionFieldMapper throw exception  "contexts field is not supported for field:...

```
"name": {
          "type": "completion",
          "contexts": [
            {
              "name": "year",
              "type": "category",
              "path": "year"
            }
          ]
        },
        "year": {
          "type": "text"
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please provide more details? What have you tried so far? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @zohar.kom new description of my problem

Answer (score 0):

It is already supported, you can find the example here [DATAES-536](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/241). For lower version, you need to write a custom completion model and use field @Mapping instead of @CompletionField.

```
public class CustomCompletion {

    private String[] input;
    private Map<String, List<String>> contexts;
    private Integer weight;

    private CustomCompletion() {
        // required by mapper to instantiate object
    }

    public CustomCompletion(String[] input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    // Setter getter

}

@Document(indexName = "compl_index")
public class ComplIndex {

    @Mapping(mappingPath = "/mapping/compl-index-suggestions.json")
    private CustomCompletion suggestions;

}
```

compl-index-suggestions.json

```
{
  "type": "completion",
  "contexts": [
    {
      "name": "year",
      "type": "category"
    }
  ]
}
```